# Split Python dictionary when multiple values for single key

Tags: python

I have Python dictionaries that sometimes have, for a single key, multiple values indicated by a comma separation (e.g. "value1, value2").  In those instances, I need to separate the dictionary into however many multiple values there are (see bottom of question for example of desired output).  There can only be one value per one key in the dictionary, otherwise it needs to be an entirely separate dictionary.

I was trying to iterate through dictionary and use popitem function when value with multiple values found.  And then create separate dictionaries and append them.  But I run into run time errors.  And I suspect there are more elegant solutions possible.

For example

```py
x = {"name":"alice", "age":20,"hobby":"badminton, basketball", "language":"python"}
for eachkey, value in x.items():
    if ", " in value:
        x.popitem()
```

Get the following error before getting any further :

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

This is an example of expected input and output :

**Input**

```
x = {"name":"alice", "age":20,"hobby":"badminton, basketball", "language":"python"}
```

**Output**

```
[
    {"name":"alice", "age":20,"hobby":"badminton", "language":"python"},
    {"name":"alice", "age":20,"hobby":"basketball", "language":"python"}
]
```

Or another example with *multiple keys with multiple values* :
(edited + included for clarification after @isaactfa answered)

**Input**

```
x = {"name":"alice", "age":20,"hobby":"badminton, basketball", "language":"python, go"}
```

**Output**

```
[
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'badminton', 'language': 'python'}, 
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'badminton', 'language': 'go'}, 
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'basketball', 'language': 'python'}, 
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'basketball', 'language': 'go'}
]
```

Comment: Do you need to create a new variable (e.g. `y`, `z`) for each new dictionary? I'd suggest using a list of dictionaries for this.

Comment: instead of popping from the existing dictionary, create new dictionaries and add items to them

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yes they need to be separate variables.  They will be sent to a database and will not be accepted as a list.

Comment: @Ollie You do not know beforehand how many dictionaries you need to create or which particular key/values require the splitting.  But show me an example if you have something concrete in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `product()`:

```
from itertools import product

x = {"name":"alice", "age":20,"hobby":"badminton, basketball", "language":"python"}

vals = [v.split(', ') if isinstance(v, str) else [v] for v in x.values()]
print([dict(zip(x, p)) for p in product(*vals)])
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'badminton', 'language': 'python'},
 {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'basketball', 'language': 'python'}]
```

Comment: Thanks Mykola!  I can confirm it works even when multiple keys have multiple values. It is more concise than @georg solution.

Comment: Indeed, this is even simpler, I'd use a comprehension instead of `map` though: `m=[x.split(', ') if isinstance(x, str) else [x] for x in dct.values()]`

Comment: Thanks @georg for being so gracious!  And yes a comprehension is at least more legible.

Answer (score 4):

I'd start by converting the input into a list of lists of key-value tuples (oh well)

```
def unwrap(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, str):
            yield [(k, v2.strip()) for v2 in v.split(',')]
        else:
            yield [(k, v)]
```

so that with

```
d = {
    "name": "alice",
    "age": 20,
    "hobby": "badminton, basketball",
    "language": "python, go"
}
```

it would return

```
[
    [('name', 'alice')], 
    [('age', 20)], 
    [('hobby', 'badminton'), ('hobby', 'basketball')], 
    [('language', 'python'), ('language', 'go')]
]
```

Once this is done, apply `itertools.product` to convert this to a  list of all possible dicts:

```
result = [
    dict(x)
    for x in product(*unwrap(d))
]
```

with `result` being

```
[
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'badminton', 'language': 'python'}, 
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'badminton', 'language': 'go'}, 
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'basketball', 'language': 'python'}, 
    {'name': 'alice', 'age': 20, 'hobby': 'basketball', 'language': 'go'}
]
```

Comment: Thanks @georg!  Obviously those 156K points are well deserved! I learned something new with the itertools library.  It covers the case of multiple keys with multiple values.  Don't think it can get any more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: This does not yield all permutations of dictionaries if more than one key has more than one value. If that is what you need, check out @georg's answer.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

This should give you the desired output:

```
def make_dicts(x):
    tuples = [(k, *(s.strip() for s in v.split(","))) if isinstance(v, str) else (k, v) for k, v in x.items()]
    most_values = max(len(t) for t in tuples) - 1
    for i in range(most_values):
        yield {k: v[i % len(v)] for k, *v in tuples}
```

You can now iterate over `make_dicts(x)` to retrieve your new dictionaries, or do `list(make_dicts(x))` to get them in a list.

The way it works is, it first makes a list of tuples containing the key as the first element and each comma separated value after it. I then find the largest of those tuples, because that is how many new dictionaries will be created (subtracting 1 for the key). For every new dictionary I now just tell it to put the key, and then the next value, wrapping the index with a modulo so keys with only one value get duplicated.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: It's a very well written code but one issue with this is that when there are multiple keys with more than one values, it won't do permutation and combination on them. For example, if age is `"20, 30"` and hobby is `"badminton, basketball"`, there should be 4 dictionaries with not 2 but this code will only generate 2.

Comment: @mnis Yea that's true but it didn't seem like that was a requirement. The only requirement was "There can only be one value per key" and the input got the output the op wanted. Thanks for complimenting my code though :)

Comment: If that is what you need, I can take another look at it @mnis. I just didn't get that impression from your question.

Comment: Yes please do @isaactfa .  I will clarify my question to include an example where more than one key has multiple values .

Comment: In that case, use @georg's answer, it's lovely.