# Split a dictionary containing list as values

Tags: python

I am currently doing

```
dicta, dictb = {},{}
for key in resultdict:
    dicta[key] = resultdict[key][0]
    dictb[key] = resultdict[key][1]
```

I want to go from this dictionary:

```
resultdict = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2'], 'key2': ['val1', 'val2'], 'key3': ['val1', 'val2'], 'key4': ['val1', 'val2']}
```

To 2 dictionaries like this:

```
dicta = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val1', 'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val1'}
```

and

```
dictb = {'key1': 'val2', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val2', 'key4': 'val2'}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what code you are using, making sure to use the code formatting tool `{}` so it displays properly.

Comment: There's no way to process an arbitrary length sequence *without* looping. (Or the recursive equivalent.)

Comment: You have to use loops but there are some tricks you can use. See this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951419/split-python-dictionary-when-multiple-values-for-single-key

Answer (score 1):

```
    dicta = {key: resultdict.get(key)[0] for key in resultdict.keys()}
    dictb = {key: resultdict.get(key)[1] for key in resultdict.keys()}
```

While this solution may be more compact, there is in general no solution other than looping through your dictionary in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

You could use zip on the values and feed the results to the dictionary constructor:

```
resultdict = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2'], 'key2': ['val1', 'val2'],
              'key3': ['val1', 'val2'], 'key4': ['val1', 'val2']}

d1,d2 = [ dict(zip(resultdict,vals)) for vals in zip(*resultdict.values()) ]

print(d1)
{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val1', 'key3': 'val1', 'key4': 'val1'}

print(d2)
{'key1': 'val2', 'key2': 'val2', 'key3': 'val2', 'key4': 'val2'}
```